# Remote debugging of a Java application launched as a Windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, remote-debugging

My Java application is started from within a native program through java.dll. This native program is launched as a service on Windows.

The following options have been added to the JVM args for remote debugging:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

In this configuration, it is impossible to connect from e.g. my Eclipse workspace. If the program is launched from the command-line, i.e. not as a service, I can connect to port 8787.

How can I allow remote debugging connections to this service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference if it runs as a service or from command line.

Please double-check that java.exe receives those command line params when started as service.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338520/ where it is pointed out that in Configuration Panel (tomcat7w) the options must not be in the same line ;/