# java remote debugging Tomcat app: Why does the JVM not listen?

Tags: java, tomcat7, remote-debugging

I want to remote debug an application running in Tomcat 7. Tomcat is running as a service on a Win2008 server.
I added the following to the Java options in the Java Configuration Panel of Tomcat:
`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4711,server=y,suspend=n` and opened the firewall on my workstation and the server for this port.
But when I try debugging from IntelliJ 9 on my workstation, I get an error message `Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"`. The jvm is the standatd Sun/Oracle 64 bit JVM version 1.6.0_27.

I verified that the command line parameters are in use by accessing `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()` within the application deployed to Tomcat and logging the result to the log file.
I verified via Wireshark on my workstation and on the server that the TCP request on port 4711 is sent from my pc and arriving on the server, but there is is no answer. Running `netstat -a` on the server does not show a process listening on this port. So I assume somehow Tomcat/JVM does not start the remote debugging.

Comment: Are you starting tomcat with jpda switch? Like: `catalina jpda start` ?

Comment: No, do I need to do this?

Comment: Yes, starting catalina with JPDA switch lets tomcat know that you want to start with debug options. Also I noticed that you're wanting to define your address has 4711 (instead of the default 8000) so keep in mind that you must define the env variable JPDA_ADDRESS to 4711. With this modifications you'll be able to attach to tomcat for debug.

Comment: How can i do this? Changing the value from `start` to `jpda start` in the Tomcat configuration GUI that pops up via the tray icon results in the service not starting with the message `Bootstrap: command "jpda start" does not exist.`

Comment: No you do not need to use jdpa. If you read the documentation ( http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1 ) you'll see that starting the service with `catalina jpda start` is a shorthand if you're working with **shell scripts** ie. not if you're using the service wrapper.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to put -Xdebug and -Xrunjdwp... on *separate lines* in the Java panel of the Tomcat Service Configuration Panel.

So having:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4711,server=y,suspend=n
```

will not work, but:

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4711,server=y,suspend=n
```

will.

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you!

Comment: I added this under the "serverenv.sh" on Linux